# mac os vi disable,and reminder me "UltiSnips requires py >= 2.6 or any py3"

Tags: macos, vi

I update my Python version to 3.4,then delete the python2.7 floders , /usr/bin/(pydoc/python/pythonw/python-config),here is the error

```
UltiSnips requires py >= 2.6 or any py3
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#bootstrap#Bootstrap:
line   14:
E168: :finish used outside of a sourced file
line   28:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   29:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   30:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   32:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   33:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   34:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
line   35:
E448: Could not load library function PyInt_AsLong
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Do `vim --version`, see if it is `+python` or `+python3`. My bet is you have both of them at `-python`, `-python3`. Which means your Vim is not compiled with Python (or, *just possibly*, that you've deleted the libraries that Vim was linked against). Recompile Vim (or install Vim that is actually compiled against Python 3.4 libraries you have).

Comment: Are you using vim or neovim ?